# Silverlight 2d Rendering Options

Tags: performance, silverlight-4.0, cross-platform, xna

I'm working on a game that I'm developing in Silverlight, and I'm trying to decide on the best implementation, performance wise. I don't expect the game to be very intensive, but doing it the right way always beats doing it the easy way. The two options I've considered are either using [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28VS.95%29.aspx) and manually draw everything and the other option is using [Silversprite](http://silversprite.codeplex.com). I did some searching, but I couldn't find any performance comparisons, so which option is faster? Also, Silversprite uses XNA, does this mean it wont work on Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SilverSprite is an *implementation* of the XNA API on top of Silverlight. So it's not actually the "real" XNA. So your platforms are limited to what Silverlight will run on - so, yes, it will run on Mac.

Performance-wise, WriteableBitmap is unusably slow for anything non-trivial.

Using Silverlight elements to render your scene can be very fast - even hardware accelerated - but it requires a lot of messing about and knowledge of how Silverlight works under-the-hood to get a good result.

My experience with SilverSprite is that it is slow and buggy, and it's also missing quite a few important XNA features.

As a bit of a coincidence - and a shameless plug - I have written an alternate implementation of XNA that runs on Silverlight with hardware acceleration ([example](http://andrewrussell.net/lightblocks/)) - so it's very fast. And I'm *just a few days* away from making an announcement about it. Feel free to email me for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I'll definitely contact you about your project.

Comment: The project I mentioned in my answer is now seeking funding via RocketHub http://rockethub.com/projects/752-exen-xna-for-iphone-android-and-silverlight